# Apache velocity - compare with random number

Tags: html, apache, velocity

How would I check if a string matches these conditions:

```
#if ($x.contains("http://www.google.com/*"))
#macro
#else
#other-macro
#end
```

Where * represents ANY number. For example http://www.google.com/9430857
This doesn't work - is there a way to represent 'any value' in velocity? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`if ($x.indexOf("http://www.google.com/") == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
#if ($x.matches("http://www.google.com/[0-9]+")
...
```

This way you avoid matching google.com links without the trailing digits.